# Cannot check userid from session in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Problem in code for checking if user id is set or not, i am using this code in checking whether a user is logged in or not.

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent:: _construct() ;
    if( ! $this->session->userdata('user_id') )
    return redirect ('login');
}
```

Output:

```
logged in page can still be accessed by entering url.
```

Comment: Then, session might have the data yet

Comment: Does this do the wrong think when the user is supposed to have been logged out, or when the user is supposed to be logged in or both

Comment: start the session first in autoload file n then check session is set or not

Comment: or using controller-  $this->load->library('session');

Comment: Did you  load `library('session');` manually or in your autoload

Comment: Can you remove `return` inside `return redirect ('login');` ?

Comment: as per CodeIgniter docs  redirect should be redirect ('login');

Comment: if already session set mean you can access the page using typing url . so clear the session like this  session_destroy(); and try again .

Comment: already added in autoload , but not working

Comment: 1. user is supposed to logged out. #RiggsFolly  2.already set in autoload file. #dee_wab   3. removed return from return redirect. #norlihazmey.   4. already session is destroyed. #jyothi.   STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION); if you want to know. The session is not set, post your code where you set your session.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have set session using `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id','value');`.Then check whether session is set or not using `$this->session->has_userdata('user_id');`

```
public function _construct()
    {
    parent:: _construct() ;
    if($this->has_session->userdata('user_id'))
    redirect('login');
}
```

Also remove return from here `return redirect('login');`.You can either `return` or `redirect` but not both at the same time.

For more see docs once [Codeigniter Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set the session using

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id','value');
```

Then check the session and redirect if not set using below code,

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_id')){
redirect ('login','refresh');
}
```

You can not use return because this is not function which is called and you are returning something, redirect helper function will automatically redirect on login page.

thank you

Comment: this is my code for setting userdata , although i have added that too previously,

Comment: see code : if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
   
   return redirect ('admin/dashboard');

Comment: In logout code you have unset the session like 
$this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
have you unset this way?

and remove the "return" keyword before "redirect", you can not return this function call this is helper function.